# Como ler uma string usando input no Java?

Tags: java

No caso eu sei fazer com `int` que seria algo como:

```
number1 = input.nextInt();
```

Mas quero que meu usuário digite uma string, vamos supor um mês:

```
mes = input.????
```

Preciso ler a string em um `switch`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
switch (mes) {
  case "janeiro": System.out.println("Nesta data ocorre o evento chamado: Feriado de janeiro");
  break;
```

Comment: Tente `input.next()`.

Answer (score 2):

Olha eu recomendo a utlização da biblioteca java.util para usar um Scanner. Segue o código abaixo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Leitura{
     public static void main(String[] args){
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

         //Aqui  você passa o valor para um string
         String valor_lido = s.nextLine();

         //Agora é fazer o que quiser com o valor dessa String

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa o `input.nextLine();` para ler a linha introduzida pelo utilizador.

Nesse caso especifico podes usar o `input.next();` porque só queres ler uma palavra sem espaços. O `next()` só lê a primeira palavra até aparecer um espaço. O `nextLine();` lê a linha inteira que possa introduzir até introduzir `"\n"` (a tecla *enter*)

Comment: se eu quiser ler a string com os espaços, mas sem o \n? Se eu digitar André Nascimento, não vou ler o 'nascimento' se usar obj.next()?

Answer (score 1):

Além do que já foi respondido, tem o `JOptionPane.showInputDialog();`
que cria uma *interfacezinha* para o usuario digitar.