# preencher como dados um Array até um valore especifico

Tags: java, array, matriz, while, for

Preciso fazer um programa que leia os nomes do teclado até que o usuário digite a palavra "fim", e então imprima os nomes digitados na ordem em que foram digitados.

Até agora, já tentei resolver essa questão usado `ArrayList`, desta forma:

```
public class Exercicios {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> nomes = new ArrayList<>();

        while(!nomes.contains("fim")){

            for(int i = 0; i < nomes.size();i++){

                System.out.println("informes quantos dados desejar e digite 'fim' para finalizar");
                nomes.add(nomes.get(i));
                System.out.println(nomes.toString());

            }  
        }
    }
 }
```

Lembrando que pro compilador, nenhum erro apresentou, porém não aparece nenhum resultado. O que será que pode esta acontecendo?

Comment: Poste o que você já tem feito, não iremos fazer sua tarefa.

Comment: Por favor de uma lida, [nesta página](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), de como se deve perguntar.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pelas dicas. Bom, até agora tudo que eu escrevi relacionado a esta questão foi o seguinte. Lembrando que pro compilador, nenhum erro apresentou, porém não aparece nenhum resultado. O que será que pode esta acontencendo, como você poderiam me ajudar com este problema?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você esqueceu de preencher o `ArrayList` de nomes antes do for. Esta linha `nomes.add(nomes.get(i));` também não faz muito sentido.

Traduzindo, você deveria tirar o `for`, ler o valor com algo com o `System.in` ou com o `JOptionPane` e verificar antes de imprimir. Na lógica seria algo como:

```
do {
   System.out.println("informes quantos dados desejar e digite 'fim' para finalizar");
   String nome = ... // aqui você lê o nome
   if (nome.equals("fim")) {
      break;
   } else {
      // adiciona na lista aqui
   }
} while(true);
```

Tente aí, se você continuar não conseguindo, poste suas alterações e até onde você conseguiu chegar.

Answer (score 0):

O seu código basicamente não recebe os dados. Acho que essa é a confusão, pois `nomes.get()` não faz leitura de dados.

Para um programa simples, você pode usar a classe `Scanner`, como [nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26239/227).